# I need to construct table like below, dynamically using pivot or unpivot

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot, unpivot

`EmpSalary` table:

```
EmpCode BASIC   HRA  CONV
--------------------------
   1    10000   500  300
   2    10000   500  300
```

Desired output:

```
   SalaryCode   SalaryDetails
    EmpCode           1
    BASIC           10000
    HRA               500
    CONV              300
   Total            10800

    EmpCode           2
    BASIC           10000
    HRA               500
    CONV              300
   Total            10800
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we need what `DBMS` are you using.

The following code that includes `unpivot` clause works for `Sql-Server` or `Oracle` :

```
select SalaryCode, SalaryDetails
  from   
   (select EmpCode, BASIC,HRA,CONV,
           (BASIC+HRA+CONV) sub_Total  
      from EmpSalary 
      ) p  
unpivot  
   (SalaryDetails for SalaryCode in
      (EmpCode,BASIC,HRA,CONV,sub_Total)  
) unpvt;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/FBQA48363)

Comment: @Akram dynamically ..? But I didn't hardcode any value(literal or integer) set explicitly ...